# state clean up behavior with flink interval join

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading at

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#interval-joins,

It has following example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders o, Shipments s
WHERE o.id = s.order_id
AND o.order_time BETWEEN s.ship_time - INTERVAL '4' HOUR AND s.ship_time
```

I got following two questions:

1. If `o.order_time` and `s.ship_time` are normal time column, not event time attribute, then all the states will be saved in Flink, like normal regular inner join does? So that, maybe big size states will be kept in Flink
2. If `o.order_time` and `s.ship_time` are event time attributes, then flink will rely on watermark to do state clean up? so that small size states will be kept in Flink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The reason Flink SQL has the notion of time attributes is so that suitable streaming queries can have their state automatically cleaned up, and an interval join is an example of such a query. Time windows and temporal joins on versioned tables also work in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks @david-anderson for the helpful answer!